# Not receiving admin order confirmation email from the website Prestashop 1.6.1.1

Tags: email, admin, prestashop, orders

I am not getting admin order confirmation email after the successful payment. I am getting payment notification from sisow but not from website. Customer is receiving confirmation email but not admin. I am new in prestashop and didn't find any solution.

Please suggest me to make it working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To receive emails as admin you need to enable one module named "Email Alerts". Enable this module and configure this module. You will see all the setting here. Go through that and set it up accordingly. You can add multiple email ids to receive notifications.

Hope this helps you !!! :)

Comment: Download link please?

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/134905-free-module-mail-alerts-23/

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you have properly configured in settings like:

> Advance Preferences -> E-mail

It's highly recommended to use **SMTP** instead of `mail()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Install the module "Mail alerts" to your prestashop project.
It solved my problem for the version 1.6.1.5

Answer (score -1):

i think i got the trick : copy all emails in modules/mailalerts/lang. 
should have the same in EN and YOUR LANG. 
Also copy in /themes/same_path

Comment: This question was asked, answered and accepted in 2015. Your answer does not contribute to the question at hand, as the original poster already indicated that the issue had been resolved. Please refer to [answer] for more info.